# How can i pass data from one HTML page to another using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-listener

Im having a hard time passing data from one HTML page to another.
Im building an online store, i have one page with my items, and with their buttons for users to pick.
and i have seconde page that is my checkout page.
I want to make it so that when the user clicks on the items in the items page it will get written on the DOM on the checkout page.
2 main issues im having:

1 inside the javascript file i have for both pages, i have the variables and eventListerner for the buttons from the items page, and i also have the variable for the table in the checkout page where i want to write with the DOM.
When im on the items page, my table variable comes as null when `console.log`.
And when im on the checkout page i get:

```
itemsScript.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at addEventListeners (itemsScript.js:44)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at itemsScript.js:46
```

So i see that they are not comunicating properly.

2 where should i put the value and names of the items, on the buttons themself? maybe a data.js file, and the how could i get this data from the button that was clicked?

Comment: you can save the item ids and the quantities in the localStorage for example, save in one page, navigate, read on the other page...

Comment: Are the 'pages' separate documents or are you just replacing some HTML?

Comment: Im using 2 seperate documents.

Answer (score 2):

Is the checkout page a complete new site or implemented inside your product site?

In case of a complete new site you will trigger a new request. One way is using local storage/cache as one already mentioned. This would probably the best solution so you wont lose any items on a normal site reload.

In case of a implemtation direct on the product site have a look at ajax. This might help you.

Comment: Yes the checkout page is a complete new page.
This online store is just for learning/training purpose, ill have to do a bit of research on how to use local storage/cache.